# Deriving probability of events

Tags: probability

I have to derive the probability of events $A$, $B$, $C$.

One selects 13 cards from a deck of 52 cards.
$A$ denotes a selection of six spades, $B$ denotes a selection of four cards of the same value, and $C$ denotes a selection of one pair of queens and one pair of aces.

How should I do this?

Comment: Would a hand with seven spades be included in $A$? Would four queens and three aces be included in $C$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm seven spades can't be included in $A$. It can't include in C four queens and three aces. C denotes only one pair of queens and one pair of aces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total number of ways to select $13$ out of $52$ cards is $\binom{52}{13}=635013559600$.

---

The number of ways to select exactly $6$ spades is $\binom{13}{6}\cdot\binom{52-13}{13-6}=26393687892$.

Hence $P(A)=\frac{26393687892}{635013559600}\approx4.156\%$.

---

Can you do the rest?

Comment: Yes! Thank you! :)

Comment: @Ganjira: You're welcome :)

Comment: Hi! Can you explain how did you count $\binom{52}{13}=635013559600$? Thanks

Comment: @Ganjira: $\frac{52!}{13!\cdot(52-13)!}$